# java swing dynamically adding components

Tags: java, swing, components, dynamic

I am new to Java Swing. I have some doubt regarding adiing components dynamically in Swing.

Basically  I hav one Main `JPanel` consisting of two sub `JPanel` (leftpanel and rightpanel ) which alligned horizontally.In left `JPanel` I hav some `JButtons`, when I will click on `JButton` I nedd to show some `JLabel`, `JTextArea` etc in right `JPanel`. I tried a code but its not working .When I click on the button its going inside the event listener function but `JLabel` I am not able to view.

I am giving my code below. Pls look at this and correct me. thanks in advance

```
package my;

    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    /**
     *
     * @author root
     */

    public class myAplliwithPanel extends JFrame{

        JPanel rightPanel;

        public myAplliwithPanel() {
             initGui();
        }        

        public void initGui()
        {
           JPanel mainPanel=new JPanel();
           mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

           JPanel leftPanel=new JPanel();
           leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            rightPanel=new JPanel();
           rightPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

           JButton dbBut=new JButton("DB");
           JButton appliBut=new JButton("Appli");
           appliBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    JLabel label=new JLabel("dsggs");
                   rightPanel.add(label);
                }
            });

           JButton backendBut=new JButton("Backend");

           leftPanel.add(dbBut);
           leftPanel.add(appliBut);
           leftPanel.add(backendBut);    

           mainPanel.add(leftPanel);
           mainPanel.add(rightPanel);

           add(mainPanel);

            setTitle("System Manger");
            setSize(400, 400);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    myAplliwithPanel myObj = new myAplliwithPanel();
                    myObj.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I edided your post please revert if isn't ...

Answer (score 23):

You need to call `revalidate` after adding (or removing) components:

```
rightPanel.add(label);
rightPanel.revalidate();
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I also tried invalidate, repaint, getParent().invalidate() / repaint() (and both together), but it just did not do the trick. My problem was I was removing all components from a JPanel and then re-adding them and they did appear once I minimized / resized the window just as I wanted them to. revalidate() on the Panel, that you are adding components to, did the trick for me, too. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

call

```
rightPanel.revalidate();
rightPanel.repaint();
```

after adding

Answer (score 4):

just add this line after you add the label

rightPanel.updateUI();

when you add any component at runtime you need to update the ui using this method

Comment: `updateUI` is to do with the look and feel, not the layout.

Comment: In Swing, the terms `layout`, `look and feel`, and `UI` have very specific meanings. The user interface (not the Swing `UI`) is composed of all three. This question is about a change to the layout (specifically, adding a new component), but your answer refers to the look and feel, hence the downvote.

Comment: @Cameron sorry dear but m not satisfy with your comment as per the answer was right and saying about the UI in that control, layout are involves.

Comment: @CameronSkinner i agree with Pratik here, the answer that he provided was in accordance to the subject of the question. maybe it didn't help in this case but others may use this answer non the less. upvoted to balance the negative score.